# How to skip a database if it fails to connect in SQL?

Tags: oracle

There are 4 databases available. I'm running a batch daily to fetch some data.

If one of them fails to connect that batch operation will be stopped.

Is there any way to skip the database if it fails to connect?

Error with database are like

> TNsname could not be resolved.
>   Lsnrtcl status is unknown .. etc..

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which language or application framework you are using but most languages have `try/catch` constructs.  You put your connection to a db in the try block and if it fails, it goes into the catch where you can log the failure or do whatever you want or simply do nothing (not recommended but possible) but the nice thing about it is it makes sure the program does not abort because of the caught incident.  E.g. in Java:

```
Connection cxn = null;

try {
   cxn = SomeConnectionFactory.getConnection(...);
} catch (SqlException sqlEx) {
   logger.info("Connection to xyz failed");
}
```

Most other languages' try/catch blocks are similarly structured.  There is also a `finally` clause that can be optionally appended to the end of it where you put stuff you want to happen whether the try succeeded or failed.

In your case, you would probably want to have some kind of a loop within which you iterate through all the prospective connections you want to make and nest such a try/catch block so that if one of the connections fail, the master loop proceeds onto the next iteration.